# How to add Next and Previous in Access form using ADODB

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb

I have a small favor to ask, I am done as much research as I can and have gotten this far with what I want to do. Here is my code:

Here is the Module Code:

```
Global con As New ADODB.Connection
Global NoRecords As Boolean

Public Enum rrCursorType
rrOpenDynamic = adOpenDynamic
rrOpenForwardOnly = adOpenForwardOnly
rrOpenKeyset = adOpenKeyset
rrOpenStatic = adOpenStatic
End Enum

Public Enum rrLockType
rrLockOptimistic = adLockOptimistic
rrLockReadOnly = adLockReadOnly
End Enum


Public Function OpenMyRecordset(rs As ADODB.Recordset, strSQL As String, Optional rrCursor As rrCursorType, Optional rrLock As rrLockType, Optional bolClientSide As Boolean) As ADODB.Recordset

If con.State = adStateClosed Then
    con.ConnectionString ="Driver= {SQLServer};Server=logistics.xxx.com;Database=ITM;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    con.Open
End If

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = con

    If bolClientSide Then
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Else
        .CursorLocation = adUseServer
    End If

    .CursorType = IIf((rrCursor = 0), adOpenStatic, rrCursor)
    .LockType = IIf((rrLock = 0), adLockReadOnly, rrLock)
    .Open strSQL

    If .EOF And .BOF Then
        NoRecords = True
        Exit Function
    End If

End With

End Function
```

Here is the full code behind the search button on the form:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

'UPC Search
If Me.chkUPCSearch = False Then

                strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT[PO Master Data Table].[PO Nbr], [PO Master Data Table].UPC, [PO Master Data Table].[Item Description], " _
                & "[PO Master Data Table].[Vendor Style], [PO Master Data Table].COO, [PO Master Data Table].[Currency Type], [PO Master Data Table].Cost, " _
                & "[PO Master Data Table].[Assist $ Amount], [PO Master Data Table].[Supplier Name], [Vendor Table].[Manufacturer Name], " _
                & "[Vendor Table].[Manufacturer Address], [Master HTS Table].[HTS DESCRIPTION], [PO Master Data Table].[Order Qty], " _
                & "[PO Master Data Table].[Qty Recieved], [PO Master Data Table].[PO Comments], " _
                & "[Master HTS Table].[HTS 1], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 2], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 3], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 4], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 5], " _
                & "[Master HTS Table].[HTS 6], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 7], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 8], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 9], [Master HTS Table].[HTS 10], " _
                & "[Master HTS Table].[Canada HTS 1], [Master Shared Compliance Review].[SCR ID] " _
                & "FROM (([PO Master Data Table] LEFT JOIN [Master HTS Table] ON [PO Master Data Table].[Vendor Style] = [Master HTS Table].[Vendor Style]) " _
                & "LEFT JOIN [Master Shared Compliance Review] ON ([PO Master Data Table].UPC = [Master Shared Compliance Review].UPC) AND ([PO Master Data Table].[PO Nbr] = [Master Shared Compliance Review].[PO Number])) " _
                & "LEFT JOIN [Vendor Table] ON [PO Master Data Table].[Vendor Style] = [Vendor Table].[Vend Style] " _
                & "WHERE [PO Nbr] = '" & Me.txtSearch & "'"

OpenMyRecordset rstRSCH, strSQL

With rstRSCH
    If .RecordCount = 0 Then
        Answer = MsgBox("The record you are searching for does not exist. Please verify you have typed it in correctly! Do you need to create an SCR Record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, " ERROR!")

        If Answer = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Manual SCR Entry - Record Search"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Answer = vbNo Then
            Me.Refresh
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Else
    .MoveNext
    .MovePrevious
        Me.txtPO.Value = rstRSCH("PO Nbr")
        Me.txtUPC.Value = rstRSCH("UPC")
        Me.txtItemDesc.Value = rstRSCH("Item Description")
        Me.txtStyleNbr.Value = rstRSCH("Vendor Style")
        Me.txtSuppNM.Value = rstRSCH("Supplier Name")
        Me.txtMFGNM.Value = rstRSCH("Manufacturer Name")
        Me.txtMFGAdd.Value = rstRSCH("Manufacturer Address")
        Me.txtHTSDESC.Value = rstRSCH("HTS Description")
        Me.txtSCRID.Value = rstRSCH("SCR ID")
        Me.txtQTY.Value = rstRSCH("Order Qty")
        Me.txtCost.Value = rstRSCH("Cost")
        Me.txtAssist.Value = rstRSCH("ASSIST $ AMOUNT")
        Me.txtCOO.Value = rstRSCH("COO")
        Me.txtHTS1.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 1")
        Me.txtHTS2.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 2")
        Me.txtHTS3.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 3")
        Me.txtHTS4.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 4")
        Me.txtHTS5.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 5")
        Me.txtHTS6.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 6")
        Me.txtHTS7.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 7")
        Me.txtHTS8.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 8")
        Me.txtHTS9.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 9")
        Me.txtHTS10.Value = rstRSCH("HTS 10")
        Me.txtCANHTS.Value = rstRSCH("Canada HTS 1")
    End If

End With

End If

Set rstRSCH = nothing`enter code here`
```

Here is where I need some help. The above works great it is using ADODB.connections and returns results. But if I search for PO **XYZ** and I know it has two lines/records associated with it; it is only showing me record **1 of 1** in the form. How to I get the record selectors to show **1 of 2** or **2 of 2** respectively?

I started to head down the path of .movenext, .moveprevious, methods but then I got confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The above code is severely dumbed down to just drive home the idea. It does call a function called OpenMyRecordset so the bulk of the connection info is in there.

Comment: Does recordcount return the correct count?

Comment: Alex, the query does show a result but only showing the first record of the search. so I know for PO# **XYZ** there should be **2** records. When searching for **XYZ** it is only showing **1 of 1** on the form in stead of the **1 of 2** that I know that is there. HTH Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208624(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Alex, Ok, that reads like stereo instructions. I get the gist and I assume I am to be looking at the  Show the RecordCount property after populating the Recordset section. But I am not sure how this will help. Again I admit I am thick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fully initialize the recordset by using `.MoveLast` and then `.MoveFirst` as long as it contains records:

```
If .RecordCount = 0 Then
    Answer = Msgbox("string",vbokonly,"title")
Else
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
End If
```

Note that, on large recordsets, this might cost you some performance.

Comment: Erik, Thank you for your quick response. does the .movefirst and .movelast show in the record selectors of the form? I just dropped this in just after the **Else** and before my value fields. But it just shows one of the two records eg **1 of 1** and not **1 of 2**. I am admittedly thick so I might not be getting this right off the bat.

Comment: Eh... you need to call this on the form's recordset (e.g. `Me.Recordset`.) Then it should just work.

Comment: Erik, So would I just use ** me.recordset = rs **. Sorry I hit enter to quickly. or would I need to open the connection on the form load and set the recordset there?

Comment: You can use `Set me.recordset = rs` (the `Set` is required) to bind the recordset to a form. But I'm a bit unclear on what you want exactly.

Comment: Erik, I owe you a brew. Thank you for squaring this away for me. :)

Comment: Erik, Argh I spoke too soon. It now shows **1 0f 2** but when I click the next record selector it doesn't change to the next line item. Did I miss something?

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue to me. Are you executing this on the `On Current` event? Because you likely should do this `On Load`.

Comment: Erik, This all rests behind a search button on the form. It is unbound and there is currently nothing programmed into the on load or the on current events for the form.

Comment: Oh, if there's truly no other code on that form, then I can't explain this behavior. You're not terminating the connection anywhere, right?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be closing the connection. in fact I haven't put a .close anywhere in the module or the form/button code.

Comment: Erik, I updated the initial post with the full module code and button code.

Comment: Hmmm.... Try to use a client-side cursor. Server-side cursors tend to cause problems on forms.